# About finding formula for an additive-combinatorial quantity

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

**The definitions:**

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. A positive integer $L$ is called $n$ **-magnificent** if in every partition of $\{ 1, ... , L \}$ into $n$ non-empty parts, at least one part contains **an arithmetic triple** (*i.e* an arithmetic progression whose length is 3). $S(n)$ is defined as **the smallest number** among the $n$-magnificent.

**The problem:**

Find the (explicit or implicit) formula, if any, of $S(n)$ with respect to $n$.

$\text{ }$

This is not an assignment. I tried to find some beginning values with computer's help. What I've found is $S(1) = 3$, $S(2) = 9$ and $S(3) = 27$. These results can be wrong, though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the [Van der Waerden numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_number) $W(3,n)$. Your values are correct; the next one is $W(3,4)=76$, and the ones after that are unknown, though the lower bounds $W(3,5)>170$ and $W(3,6)>223$ are known. According to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vanderWaerdenNumber.html) it is known that there is a constant $c$ such that

$$W(3,n)\le e^{n^c}$$

for all $n$.